# Is point a (ex. walmart) to point b (ex. los angeles) possible in Google Maps?

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

My main question is located in bold,Im currently developing a system for business which has a location(like california) to supplier(like walmart), however I was only able to do was point a(ex. los angeles) to point b(ex. san francisco) **I want to make it point a(ex. los angeles) to point b(ex. walmart) is that even possible?** here is the code I have researched, though I dont understand some of the code, I got it somewhere and edited some code in it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        function initialize() {
            var balanga = new google.maps.LatLng(14.67460421, 120.52207947);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom:10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: balanga
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

        /*Function for creating the roadmap*/
        function calcRoute(start, end, mode) {
            var request = {
                origin:start,
                destination:end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[mode]
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
             });

            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

             /*Show directions panel*/
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
        }

        initialize();
        calcRoute('Pampanga', 'Mariveles', 'DRIVING');

        jQuery('#driveit').click(function(){
            var srcAddr = jQuery('#from').val();
            var destAddr = jQuery('#to').val();
            var mode = jQuery('#mode').val();
            calcRoute(srcAddr, destAddr, mode);
        });
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<h2>Map of Bataan   </h2>
<div class="googlemap">
    <div id="map_area">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <br />
            From <input type="text" id="from" value="City of Balanga" />
            To <input type="text" id="to" value="Mariveles" />
            Travel Mode 
            <select id="mode">
                <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
                <option value="WALKING">Walking </option>
                <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling  </option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Show Route" id="driveit" />
            <br /><a href="Admin/home.php"><h2>BACK</h2></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="directions"></div>
</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using Google Distance Matrix function of Google Maps API.
But this resource of Google Maps API is limited for free use.

The limitations for free use is:

**100 elements by query.
100 elements by 10 secconds.
2500 elements by day.
And this should be used in public (read free) areas of your website/app.**

Each location is a element. If you want to compare distance between 2 points, you're using 2 elements.

If you want to compare distance of 50 address to find which is the nearest, you're using 50 elements.